# Swift 3 Line Chart Get Index

Tags: swift3, ios-charts

So Im making a graph using the Beautiful Charts Api. Im doing it in SWIFT 3. I got the graph working but now Im trying to get the selected value index, I have tried many things but they have not work. Heres my latest attempt at it.

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: 
     ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {

        if let dataSet = chartView.data?.dataSets[ highlight.dataSetIndex] {

            let Index: Int = dataSet.entryIndex( entry: entry)
            print( "Selected index: \( Index)")
        }
    }
```

[IOS GRAPH IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgYx0.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use entry.x to retrieve the x value, or isn’t that the same as the index?

`print(“/(entry.x)”)`

Comment: Hmmm It turns out the function is not even being ran, I do have the delegate setup. This would probably work as well but the problem seems to be with the function not running

Comment: Make sure you set self.chartview.delegate = self in viewdidload

Comment: Okay got it, it was the function itself. It didn't match for some reason. I had copied and pasted it. Then deleted it and just retyped it, selected it. And typed print(entry.x),,, that worked perfect! THANKS!

Comment: @DevB2F I have always `highlight ` with zero data (x, y, dataSetIndex). But I set to chart view array of highlight. Why is it so?